# How to avoid multiple service's instance in an Angular library? (with lazy loaded modules)

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a Very Big project in angular and i'm migrating the Core to a library. The problem comes when my services (in the library) was exported with:

```
public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: NbopflModule,
      providers: [
        ...ALL_PIPES,
        ...ALL_SERVICES
      ]
    };
  }
```

And the services (All of them) has:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

I load the library (forRoot) in appModule.
And i load the same library in the lacy load modules (some like a library lacy loaded, and some are inside the project)

I add a console.log in the constructor, and in every module loaded apear the message, generating multiple instances. I dont want to refactor all the code making all the variabe statics.

Anyone Knows about any way to force a single instance of a service imported by a library?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution :S:S

Its just removing all the declarations in the providers (not in forRoot, not in the module providers....) just with the provideIn: 'root', and being exported in the public-api file, works :)